# How to calculate Jensen-Shannon divergence?

Tags: functions, function-construction, probability-or-statistics, data, procedural-programming

How to write the function (or any other methods) to calculate Jensen-Shannon divergence (JSD) for two (p and q) discrete probability distributions? I need to calculate JSD for too many different (over 1000) probability distributions so it should be run able by for loop.
Thank you for your help.
I wrote the below code but it is not working. You can see the part of the probability distribution (PD) of p and q. There are a lot 0 in the both p and q PD.

```
p={0.13253, 0.0361446, 0.0120482, 0.0240964, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,0., 0., 0.,0,0}



q={0.0282448, 0.0163522, 0.010406, 0.0163522, 0.0208119, 0.0118925,
0.00891941, 0.00297314, 0.0044597, 0.00148657, 0., 0., 0., 0.,0.00148657}



Function[{p, q},   

N[1/2 (p*Log2 p + q*Log2 q) - ((p + q)/2*Log2 (p + q)/2)]][

 p@DjointProbaility, q@DmarjinalProbaility]
```

Comment: I think you'll get more help with your questions if you would show some programming effort and/or definitions of the statistics of interest.

Comment: I tried many different functions and method before asking the question.

Comment: That's much better but without examples of the `p` and `q`, how can we know what "it is not working" means.

Comment: For the user's convenience, see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen–Shannon_divergence) for info.

Comment: According to Wiki, JSD is realized in Python. Maybe, that code can be executed in Mathematica.

Comment: Jensen-Shannon divergence is only well-defined for pairs of probability distributions that are absolutely continuous with respect to each other. Meaning: both `p/q` and `q/p` must exists (without division by zero). Your example vectors just don't satisfy this, so it takes no wonder that this does not "work". This metric is just not applicable to your data.

Comment: Moreover you use parenthesis ` () ` for your function calls, not brackets `[] ` as they are used for this purpose in _Mathematica _.

Answer (score 4):

The function `cJSdiv` below is `Listable`, so when called on two vectors `p` and `q` goes through the entries and returns a vector of same length. It tests whether both are zero or both are nonzero. That's the two cases in which the summand for the Jensen-Shannon divergence is defined; then `cJSdiv` returns this summand at the corresponding position of the output vector. Otherwise the maximum double precision number `` 1.7976931348623157`*^308 `` is returned. The function `JSdiv` serves as a wrapper and performs the summation.

```
cJSdiv = Compile[{{p, _Real}, {q, _Real}},
   Block[{minv},
    If[p > 0. && q > 0.,
     minv = 2./(p + q);
     0.5 (p (Log[p minv]) + q (Log[q minv])),
     If[p == 0. && q == 0.,
      0.,
      1.7976931348623157`*^308
      ]
     ]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];

JSdiv = {p, q} |-> Total[cJSdiv[p, q]];
```

Just call it like this:

```
JSdiv[p,q]
```

Comment: Executing your code, I obtain "CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary::nocomp: A C compiler cannot be found on your system. Please consult the documentation to learn how to set up suitable compilers." and "Compile::nogen: A library could not be generated from the compiled function.".

Comment: Needs["SymbolicC`"] and Needs["CCompilerDriver`"] do not help.

Comment: Well, then you have to install a C/C++ compiler. Natural choices would be the following: Apple clang for macos; gcc or clang for Linux; Microsoft Virtual Studio for Windows. See here for instructions: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/tutorial/SpecificCompilers.html

Comment: Alternatively, you can change `CompilationTarget -> "C",` to `CompilationTarget -> "WVM",`. Then no external compiler is required, but the performance is not as nearly good.

Comment: Thank you. I used `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"` and obtained `1.258385194403621*10^309`.BTW, this differs from `1.7976931348623157*^308`.

Comment: Yes, because there were several entries for which `1.7976931348623157*^308` was returned by `cJSdiv` and `JSdiv` sums up all of them.

Comment: Indeed, their fraction is equal to  `6.999999999999999`.

Comment: Something strange. For `p = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[1, 1], 100];q = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[0.99, 1.01], 100];` I obtained `4.96253` for `JSdiv[p, q]`, whereas as [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen–Shannon_divergence) says it should be in $(0,\log 2)$.

Comment: You `p` and `q` are no probability distributions (they are no probability vectors); they are just drawn from a distributions.

Comment: As well as `p` and `q` from the question.  What does calculate your code? JSD is a real number.

Comment: That's also what confused me. I saw only on the second readthrough that OP is aware of that; they wrote "You can see the part of the probability distribution (PD) of p and q." Emphasize is on the word "part". My code calculates what I combined from these to pages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen–Shannon_divergence#Definition and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback–Leibler_divergence#Definition.

Comment: Sorry, both above  links are dead. I   find the formula programmed by you  neither [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen–Shannon_divergence) nor [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback–Leibler_divergence).